# Configure jax rpc Handler for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jax-rpc

My project uses javax.xml.rpc.handler.Handler interface to process xml received. I use weblogic. Now I am moving to tomcat and want to use javax.xml.rpc model only.

Can you help me to understand how to configure my mail class and handler configs so that after deploying on tomcat, tomcat process the request.

### My web.xml

```
<web-app>
<security-constraint>
 <display-name></display-name>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>ABC</web-resource-name>
<description>Resources to be placed under security control.</description>
<url-pattern>MyService</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>myrole</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
<description>SSL required</description>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint> 
</web-app>
```

### web-services.xml

```
<web-services xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<handler-chains>
 <handler-chain name="MyHandlerChain">
    <handler class-name="com.x1.x2.ServerHandler">        
     </handler>
 </handler-chain>       
</handler-chains>

<web-service protocol="https" name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://www.myproject.com/myservice" uri="/MyService">
<components>
  <java-class name="MyService" class-name="com.x1.x2.MyService" />
</components>
<operations>
  <operation method="sendRequestAttachment" handler-chain="MyHandlerChain" component="MyService">
    <params>
      <param name="param" style="in" type="xsd:string" />
      <return-param name="result"  type="xsd:string" />
    </params>
  </operation> 
</operations>
</web-service>
</web-services>
```